# C# SQLite connection closing

Tags: c#, sqlite

So I'm moving into storing data locally using SQLite and want to make sure I'm doing this the right way.

What is the best practice for handling this type of operation? I am trying to create a reusable connection and close it when I am finished with `command.Dispose();`. Is this the correct way to do it, or should I be creating the connection a different way?

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

public class DB
{

        public static SQLiteConnection ConnectDB()
        {
            var m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            return m_dbConnection;
        }

        public static void CreateTable()
        {

            string sql = "CREATE TABLE highscores (name VARCHAR(20), score INT)";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, ConnectDB());
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Table created");
            command.Dispose();
            
        }
}
```

In response to the comments, is the using statement used on `CreateTable()` and does `Dispose()` not have to be used as shown below?

```
    public static void CreateTable()
        {

            string sql = "CREATE TABLE highscores (name VARCHAR(20), score INT)";
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, ConnectDB()))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Table created");
            }
}
```

Comment: You can create that in your `CreateTable` method as a variable. And you can use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically.

Comment: ^^ [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: Some quick notes: 1- Not only SqLiteCommand but also SQLiteConnection implement IDisposable. 2- If your code gets an exception the unmanaged resources would not be freed... Consider using [the using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: Thank you for the information. Just for clarification, I would put the using block inside my `CreateTable()`, not in `ConnectDB()`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks reasonable, but you should be using a close rather than a dispose.  A better version would be something like

```
public class DB
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new database connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="src">An optional connection string, if null or empty the default will be used</param>
    /// <returns>A database connection</returns>
    public static SqliteConnection ConnectDB(string src = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src))
                src = "Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;";
            SqliteConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
            dbConnection.Open();
            return dbConnection;
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            // Add logging here
            throw ex;
            // or just throw to re-throw the original error
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Close the database connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dbConnection"></param>
    public static void CloseConnection(SqliteConnection dbConnection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dbConnection != null)
                dbConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // Add logging here, don't throw
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a non query and returns the number of rows updated. Use this for create, drop, insert, delete and update commands
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sqlCmd">The SQL command to execute</param>
    /// <param name="dbConnection">The database connection to use, if null an new connection will be opened and closed afterwards</param>
    /// <param name="conString">An optional DB connection string</param>
    /// <returns>The number of rows updated</returns>
    public static async Task<int> ExecuteNonQuery(string sqlCmd, SqliteConnection dbConnection = null, string conString = null)
    {
        SqliteTransaction txn = null;
        bool openedCon = false;
        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            if (dbConnection == null)
            {
                dbConnection = ConnectDB();
                openedCon = true;
            }

            SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sqlCmd, dbConnection);
            txn = command.Transaction;
            result = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            await txn.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            if(txn != null)
            {
                await txn.RollbackAsync();
            }
            // Add logging here
            throw ex;
            // or just throw to re-throw the original error
        }
        finally
        {
            if (openedCon)
                CloseConnection(dbConnection);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a command and return the result set in a data reader
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sqlCmd">The select to execute</param>
    /// <param name="dbConnection">The database connection to use, if null an new connection will be opened and closed afterwards</param>
    /// <param name="conString">An optional DB connection string</param>
    /// <returns>SqliteDataReader with results</returns>
    public static async Task<SqliteDataReader> ExecuteQuery(string sqlCmd, SqliteConnection dbConnection = null, string conString = null)
    {
        SqliteDataReader res = null;
        bool openedCon = false;
        try
        {
            if (dbConnection == null)
            {
                dbConnection = ConnectDB(conString);
                openedCon = true;
            }
            SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sqlCmd, dbConnection);
            res = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            res = null;
            // Add logging here
            throw ex;
            // or just throw to re-throw the original error
        }
        finally
        {
            if (openedCon)
                CloseConnection(dbConnection);
        }
        return res;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Run a query and return the value in the first row, first column as an object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sqlCmd">The select to execute</param>
    /// <param name="dbConnection">The database connection to use, if null an new connection will be opened and closed afterwards</param>
    /// <param name="conString">An optional DB connection string</param>
    /// <returns>The value in the first row, first column as an object</returns>
    public static async Task<object> ExecuteScalar(string sqlCmd, SqliteConnection dbConnection = null, string conString = null)
    {
        object res = null;
        bool openedCon = false;
        try
        {
            if (dbConnection == null)
            {
                dbConnection = ConnectDB(conString);
                openedCon = true;
            }
            SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sqlCmd, dbConnection);
            res = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            res = null;
            // Add logging here
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (openedCon)
                CloseConnection(dbConnection);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

You can use it something like this;

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
     SqliteConnection con = null;
     try
     {
         con = DB.ConnectDB();
         int rowCount = await DB.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE TABLE highscores (name VARCHAR(20), score INT)", con);
         rowCount = await DB.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO highscores(name, score) VALUES ('first', 1)", con);
         SqliteDataReader res = await DB.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM highscores", con);
         string maxName = (string)await DB.ExecuteScalar("SELECT max(name) FROM highscores", con);
     }
     catch (System.Exception ex)
     {
         // Resolve issue here
     }
     finally
     {
         if(con != null)
             DB.CloseConnection(con);
     }
}
```

You don't need to specifically call the dispose, when the connection object (con in this example) goes out of scope, the dispose will be called for you.  Just call Close to terminate the connection.

You could open the connection in a using block, that is up to you, but you still should close the connection before the end of the using.

Comment: `throw ex;` is more than unnecessary - it is harmful; at best it should be `throw`; but until you actually *have* some logging to add: just don't add that line *at all*. The rest of the code is IMO just bad; there's no reason whatsoever to use `try`/`finally` for the close - just `using` on the connection is fine; and `ExecuteQuery` etc are not async, from what I can see

Comment: I assumed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand?view=msdata-sqlite-3.1.0 which does have async methods, you could just use throw to rethrow the original, depends on what you do with the logging and what you want to tell the caller.

Comment: The Close method doesn't have a try/catch/finally, just a catch to make closing the connection fail silently (after logging)

Comment: you missed my point; `SqliteConnection con = null; try { con = DB.ConnectDB(); ... } finally { if (con != null) DB.CloseConnection(con);` should be *completely* replaced with just `using var con = DB.ConnectDB();` - nothing more is required, and nothing more is useful

Comment: Just trying to help Zak out with a couple of tools to interface with, he might find it useful to make his code easier to use, but yes you are correct, using(..) will automatically call dispose for you.